# Jumbotron Alignment Issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently using the latest release of bootstrap 3.0.0

The issue is simple. In the jumbotron container I use how do i center align the text with the logo

I've been playing for hours, with col-md-* and with little luck.

In bootstrap 2.3.2 I achieved the effect of centering everything in hero by using `.text-center` and `.pagination center` (for the image?? - it worked)

http://jsfiddle.net/zMSua/

This fiddle shows the text and image im trying to center with bootstrap 3.0.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another answer, that can center some content inside the actual div:

```
  <head>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <style>
            .centerfy img{
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            .centerfy{
                text-align: center;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body style=" padding: 10px;">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row well well-lg">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 centerfy">

                <h1 class="">Home of the</h1>
                <div class="">
                    <img  src="http://www.harrogatepoker.co.uk/profile/HPL%20V%20Logo%20%20Revised%20and%20Further%20reduced.jpg" class="img-responsive text-center" />
                </div>
                <h2 class="">"All In", Fun!</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Check the classes I added.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo - This is a similar fix to the one i used. 

Bootstrap Accomodate text with their class .text-center - which is simply text-align: center; however they dont have an built in class for centering images... it becomes a grid hack or something similar.

I dont understand why the dont incoporate the a class .img-center with your css style above (maybe because its a hack) ??

Answer (score 8):

why not offset the grid?

like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row well well-lg">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1 class="">Home of the</h1>
                <div class="">
                    <img src="http://www.harrogatepoker.co.uk/profile/HPL%20V%20Logo%20%20Revised%20and%20Further%20reduced.jpg" class="img-responsive text-center" />
                </div>
                <h2 class="">"All In", Fun!</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

bootstrap has a 12 column grid if your main column has 6, you can offset it 3 and will leave you with:

3 columns  6 (main container) and 3 columns

Answer (score 2):

As of Bootstrap 3.3.6, my experience of centering text and logos within a Jumbotron comes simply by adding .text-center to your .container class element, along with .img-responsive and .center-block to your image element.  I find no need to modify CSS classes or offset bootstrap regions.

Check out [my demo](http://www.bootply.com/9ixZQSqVVR).

```
  <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container text-center"> 
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <img src="http://klpgo.com/klpfiles/images/klpgov3.png" alt="img" class="img-responsive center-block">
            <p>custom text within my jumbotron</p>
            <a class="btn btn-default">first button</a>
            <a class="btn btn-info">second button</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```